# TypeError: ui is undefined with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I a have a Bootstrap Typeahead function, what I want to customize a little bit. If the user clicks on any of the items in the result dropdown list, the user would be redirected to one subpage. The typeahead function is working great, the dropdown list is populated without any error, this is one example what is return from the php file:

```
[{"name":"TEXT-ONE","url":"\/textone-postfix"},{"name":"TEXT-TWO","url":"\/texttwo-postfix"},{"name":"TEXT-THREE"
,"url":"\/textthree-postfix"}]
```

The idea is, that the "name" attribute is displayed to the user and after click, it's redirects to the "url" attribute.

The problem is that right now after I click on ANY of the items I get this error (Firefox Firebug console output):

```
TypeError: ui is undefined
```

This is my jQuery function and before that the .js imports:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
      $('#namesearch').typeahead({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/functions/search-autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + request,
            success: function(data) {
              response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    url: item.url,
                    value: item.name
                }
              }))
            }
          })
        },
        displayText: function(item) {
            return item.value
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          window.location.href = ui.item.url;
        }
      });
    });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Can someone help me please, what's the problem here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The error pretty much says that there's no second argument being passed to the `select` function in your typeahead config. Could you specify exactly which typeahead library you're using?

Comment: well, i guess the question is, how are you attaching that select function to whatever is calling it? the first part of your code does work (calls a php url)...

Comment: The library is also in the import section: bootstrap3-typeahead. I'm not really a jQuery/JS guru, so it's can be a simple conflict as well ... But it doesn't help if I add or remove the jquery-ui.min.js.

Comment: I had also problems with the dropdown population, here you can see the full code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531473/making-clickable-result-list-from-bootstrap-typeahead-and-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updater function was the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
      $('#namesearch').typeahead({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/functions/search-autocomplete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + request,
            success: function(data) {
              response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    url: item.url,
                    value: item.name
                }
              }))
            }
          })
        },
        displayText: function(item) {
            return item.value
        },
        updater: function (item) {
                window.location.href = item.url
        },
      });
    });
    });
```